# Why does Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor({}, '__proto__') return undefined?

Tags: javascript

Why does `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor({}, '__proto__')` return `undefined`?

Is it because `__proto__` was originally not actually a userland property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__proto__` is not an own property. It is a property of `Object.prototype`, which is a getter or setter implemented internally to get and set the object's prototype (`[[Prototype]]`).

```
< Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, '__proto__')
> Object {enumerable: false, configurable: true, get: function..., set: function...}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `__proto__` is an inherited property from object's `prototype`:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames({}) // prints "[]", no properties
'__proto__' in {}              // prints "true", it's inherited from prototype
```

You can get the `__proto__` descriptor from the `prototype` directly:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf({}), '__proto__');
// prints {enumerable: false, ... }
```